# IOS: Possible to Create roll your own VCard without going through CNContact?

Tags: ios, objective-c, vcf-vcard

I have an app that holds contacts in its own entity. I would like the ability to share these contacts in the form of VCards. In order to create a VCard, is it necessary to first create a CNContact and then call `cncontactvcardserialization`.

Alternatively, can you create your own VCard using strings?

Right now, my contacts have attribute names like firstname and lastname whereas cncontact uses givenname and familyname. So when I call something like:

```
NSData* vCardData = [CNContactVCardSerialization dataWithContacts:@[contact] error:&error];
```

on my version of contact, it throws the error that contact has no attribute named familyname.